# Need to replace iPhone screen. Are aftermarket parts OK?

Tags: iphone, screen

I have an iPhone 4 or 4s (not sure which) with a cracked screen that a friend of mine asked me to replace.  I see online that you can pick that part up for $20-$30, but they are all "aftermarket" (i.e. non-Apple) parts.

I've never replaced the screen on an iPhone before, but non-Apple parts in other areas (like laptop power adapters) have always given me cause for concern.

Are aftermarket knock-off parts OK?  Do they work as well as Apple OEM parts?  What is the quality like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be willing to spend about $40 for the more expensive ones, because in the end, they'll be worth it. The parts work well, but the ribbon cables are ridiculously easy to rip and tear, so be extremely careful.

The cheaper ones usually have thinner glass, thus cracking easily. Also, make sure you specify either CDMA or GSM when searching for parts as the CDMA parts are different from the GSM ones, and they're not inter-compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on my fourth aftermarket screen.

Although I never had problems with the ribbon cables tearing they ARE very delicate and make sure you pull the ribbon cable all the way through the gap before you try putting it back together (you'll see what I mean when you try it).

Also, the first 2 replacement screens I had were at the cheaper end of the market and gave a really narrow field of view. If I looked at the screen side on, at less than 60 degrees above the horizontal, the colours looked inverted.

Hope this helps. Just make sure you keep track of where all the screws go, and have a laptop with you so you can watch the repair videos on youtube as you do it.

Good luck!

Comment: I also recommend the iFixit website's iPhone repair guides for people that don't have access to Apple repair manuals.

Answer (score 0):

You'd better search Google on how to distinguish an original iPhone 4/4S screen and a copy one. There are many copies in aftermarket. I have seen many people complaining about the screen replacements from eBay and Amazon.

If you want to get one from either of them be careful not to buy the fake ones. Recently, I got an iPhone 6 screen replacement from a supplier who also installed it on my cracked phone. Now the phone is working fine.

Comment: Is there a way to see a fake (not original) part ?

Comment: Once fitted yes, bright spots on screen, poor touch response, etc... As a spare in a box, it's *very* difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0):

1) I believe from having bought several parts on Amazon and various dealers that they're no so called "original" parts… But some seems to be manufactured at the same factory as Apple ones.
2) The most comon problem I had with iPhone 4/4S is heratic touch-screen most of the time due to a piece of glass stuck on one of the corners and thus creating "bad contacts" on the touch screen matrix.

Therefore I'd recommend you either to try your luck at one dealer and see if parts are reliable and "the same" or get them thru a dealer that has a good warranty policy.

Last comment but not least beware one clipping the top of the screen to have use a plastic spudger to make sure  TS and LCD ribbon cables are fully passed inside the gap in order not to pinch them. If pinched then you'll fail part of the connections and experience part of the TS not working or lines on the screen…